# How to receive data from user Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I want to receive data from users and pass the processed version. For example user passed JSON:

```json
{"first number": 3, 

"second number": 4},
```

and the web API should response addition of numbers like {"result": 7}. How to do it without writing to the database?

My serializer.py looks like:

```
class AdditionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first = serializers.CharField()
    second = serializers.CharField()
```

views.py:

```
class AdditionView(APIView):
    @action(detail=False)
    def get_addition(self, request):
        try:
            serializer = AdditionSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                first = serializer.validated_data(['first'])
                second = serializer.validated_data(['second'])
                response = {'result': first+second}
                return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response({"message":"error"})
        except:
            None
```

but it's doesn't work

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: @RezaHeydari {
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@action` decorator is not for APIView you must use action with viewsets remove that and change method to `get`

```
class AdditionView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            serializer = AdditionSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                first = serializer.validated_data(['first'])
                second = serializer.validated_data(['second'])
                response = {'result': first+second}
                return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response({"message":"error"})
        except:
            None
```

Another thing I want mention is change serializer to use `IntergerField` rather than `CharField`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, a custom view endpoint / API will help to get a response.
Since you are using APIView, you can override the post method with addition logic and send back JSON response.